# Survival analysis metric on time series data

Tags: metric, survival-analysis

I created a model that estimates the probability of failure of an asset (based on Weibull CDF, value between 0 and 1). I have a data point every minute.

I want to measure the model's success based on the actual time to failure. I read several survival analysis articles that propose a concordance index or Brier score, but they do not seem to match my use case. Which metric should fit this case?